# Sequence with locally random integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, optimization, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I am considering the following scenario.

There is a sequence of integers. For convenience, let's assume that total number of integers is an integer multiple of $n$. Now, we can define a bucket with capacity $n$ so it can hold exactly $n$ integers. Now we have integer number of buckets each completely filled. A property of the sequence is that in each bucket, the subsequence could be in random order. However, if you take the average of each bucket, they are always in descending order (we could also imagine a situation where it is ascending).

Now let me give an example where there are $15$ numbers and $n = 5$. Consider the following sequence.

$100, 90, 95, 89, 99, 70, 75, 77, 69, 72, 53, 59, 50, 49, 54$.

Now, there are three buckets. The averages of the buckets are $94.6$, $72.6$, and $53$, so they are in descending order.

My question is, are there well known sequences which have this or similar properties?

Comment: Any descending sequence has this property.

Comment: @AndreasLenz, you are right but that is probably the trivial case, right?

Comment: That's true. Another, perhaps more prominent, example are sequences with a descending moving average (where the average is taken over $n$ consecutive values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [damped harmonic oscillator](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html) is a popular example from classical mechanics.
It can be represented as
$$
x(t) = e^{-\alpha t} \cdot \cos(\omega t + \phi)
$$
so the amplitude of the wave decreases with respect to time. This allows it to be separated into buckets of decreasing average to give a non-trivial sequence that satisfies your conditions.